# Insert Same Image Multiple Times Into Excel Using EPplus

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export, epplus

I want to insert the same image multiple times into excel using EPplus method. I researched online and tried the method in this link([Adding images into Excel using EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588704/adding-images-into-excel-using-epplus)) but I received the following error **'Name already exists in the drawings collection'** on this line:

```
var picture = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(a.ToString(), repeatimage);
```

This is my code:

```
public void ExportToExcel()
{
    //for export

        ExcelPackage objExcelPackage = new ExcelPackage();   //create new workbook

        string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath("~/Folder"));
        string repeatimagepath=@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Project\Project1\Project1\NewProject\NewProject\Image\repeatimage.png";
        Bitmap repeatimage= new Bitmap(repeatimagepath);
        int count = 0;
        int count1 = 0;
        int x = 25;
        int finalValue = 0;

        foreach (string subdir in filesindirectory)
        {
            count++;
            string[] splitter = subdir.Split('\\');
            string folderName = splitter[splitter.Length - 1];
            ExcelWorksheet ws = objExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(folderName); //create new worksheet
            count1 = 0;
            foreach (string img in Directory.GetFiles(subdir))
            {
                count1++;
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image TEST_IMAGE = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                System.Drawing.Image myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(img);
                var pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(count1.ToString(), myImage);  

                **for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
                {
                    var picture = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(a.ToString(), repeatimage);
                    picture.SetPosition(a * 5, 0, 2, 0);
                }**

                // Row, RowoffsetPixel, Column, ColumnOffSetPixel
                if (count1 > 1)
                {
                    pic.SetPosition(finalValue, 0, 2, 0);
                    finalValue += (x + 1); // Add 1 to have 1 row of empty row
                }
                else
                {
                    pic.SetPosition(count1, 0, 2, 0);
                    finalValue = (count1 + x) + 1; // Add 1 to have 1 row of empty
                }
                myImage.Dispose();
                repeatimage.Dispose();
            }
        }

        var filepath = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\" + datetime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx");
        objExcelPackage.SaveAs(filepath);
}
```

**Question: How can I insert the same image multiple times into excel using EPplus?**

Please help me on this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error already told you the answer

This line your `count1` is `1`

```
var pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(count1.ToString(), myImage);
```

Then this line

```
for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
{
    var picture = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(a.ToString(), repeatimage);
    picture.SetPosition(a * 5, 0, 2, 0);
}
```

Your `a` will be `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` as the name of the picture 
You see the error ?

Comment: yes thanks for your help @Nic! I have solved this issue :)

Comment: How to insert a picture in Excel using format Image Base64? (EPPlus)