# Open Office XML excel

Tags: excel

i am generating excel file from backend using sap. now the problem is if i want to add a content to a cell or add an image etc. i am not knowing exactly what content to place in each file that is not knowing how to use the which attributes to use in a tag at different time like if there is mearge then what to pass to row tag, when to place a string in sharedstring.xml file etc so i want to learn the xml tags used in xml generation for excel. is there any reference or tutorial to learn office xml excel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using one of the Open Office XML libraries? EPPlus is quite a good one.
Here is an example of how to do what you are asking in EPPlus:
[Adding images into Excel using EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588704/adding-images-into-excel-using-epplus)