# How to insert picture into excel using MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

Below are two methods, one uses `MemoryStream` and the other uses real file on the disk.

```
        public void InsertImage(long x, long y, long? width, long? height, string sImagePath, WorksheetPart wsp)
    {
        try
        {
            DrawingsPart dp;
            ImagePart imgp;
            WorksheetDrawing wsd;

            ImagePartType ipt;
            switch (sImagePath.Substring(sImagePath.LastIndexOf('.') + 1).ToLower())
            {
                case "png":
                    ipt = ImagePartType.Png;
                    break;
                case "jpg":
                case "jpeg":
                    ipt = ImagePartType.Jpeg;
                    break;
                case "gif":
                    ipt = ImagePartType.Gif;
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }

            if (wsp.DrawingsPart == null)
            {
                //----- no drawing part exists, add a new one

                dp = wsp.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();
                imgp = dp.AddImagePart(ipt, wsp.GetIdOfPart(dp));
                wsd = new WorksheetDrawing();
            }
            else
            {
                //----- use existing drawing part

                dp = wsp.DrawingsPart;
                imgp = dp.AddImagePart(ipt);
                dp.CreateRelationshipToPart(imgp);
                wsd = dp.WorksheetDrawing;
            }

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sImagePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                imgp.FeedData(fs);
            }

            int imageNumber = dp.ImageParts.Count<ImagePart>();
            if (imageNumber == 1)
            {
                Drawing drawing = new Drawing();
                drawing.Id = dp.GetIdOfPart(imgp);
                wsp.Worksheet.Append(drawing);
            }

            NonVisualDrawingProperties nvdp = new NonVisualDrawingProperties();
            nvdp.Id = new UInt32Value((uint)(1024 + imageNumber));
            nvdp.Name = "Picture " + imageNumber.ToString();
            nvdp.Description = "";
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PictureLocks picLocks = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PictureLocks();
            picLocks.NoChangeAspect = true;
            picLocks.NoChangeArrowheads = true;
            NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties nvpdp = new NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties();
            nvpdp.PictureLocks = picLocks;
            NonVisualPictureProperties nvpp = new NonVisualPictureProperties();
            nvpp.NonVisualDrawingProperties = nvdp;
            nvpp.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties = nvpdp;

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Stretch stretch = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Stretch();
            stretch.FillRectangle = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.FillRectangle();

            BlipFill blipFill = new BlipFill();
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip blip = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip();
            blip.Embed = dp.GetIdOfPart(imgp);
            blip.CompressionState = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.BlipCompressionValues.Print;
            blipFill.Blip = blip;
            blipFill.SourceRectangle = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.SourceRectangle();
            blipFill.Append(stretch);

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Transform2D t2d = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Transform2D();
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Offset offset = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Offset();
            offset.X = 0;
            offset.Y = 0;
            t2d.Offset = offset;
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(sImagePath);

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Extents extents = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Extents();

            if (width == null)
                extents.Cx = (long)bm.Width * (long)((float)914400 / bm.HorizontalResolution);
            else
                extents.Cx = width * (long)((float)914400 / bm.HorizontalResolution);

            if (height == null)
                extents.Cy = (long)bm.Height * (long)((float)914400 / bm.VerticalResolution);
            else
                extents.Cy = height * (long)((float)914400 / bm.VerticalResolution);

            bm.Dispose();
            t2d.Extents = extents;
            ShapeProperties sp = new ShapeProperties();
            sp.BlackWhiteMode = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.BlackWhiteModeValues.Auto;
            sp.Transform2D = t2d;
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PresetGeometry prstGeom = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PresetGeometry();
            prstGeom.Preset = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle;
            prstGeom.AdjustValueList = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.AdjustValueList();
            sp.Append(prstGeom);
            sp.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.NoFill());

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.Picture picture = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.Picture();
            picture.NonVisualPictureProperties = nvpp;
            picture.BlipFill = blipFill;
            picture.ShapeProperties = sp;

            Position pos = new Position();
            pos.X = x * 914400 / 72;
            pos.Y = y * 914400 / 72;
            Extent ext = new Extent();
            ext.Cx = extents.Cx;
            ext.Cy = extents.Cy;
            AbsoluteAnchor anchor = new AbsoluteAnchor();
            anchor.Position = pos;
            anchor.Extent = ext;
            anchor.Append(picture);
            anchor.Append(new ClientData());
            wsd.Append(anchor);
            wsd.Save(dp);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex; // or do something more interesting if you want
        }
    }

    //use memorystream
public void InsertImage(long x, long y, long? width, long? height, MemoryStream ms, WorksheetPart wsp)
        {
            try
            {
                DrawingsPart dp;
                ImagePart imgp;
            WorksheetDrawing wsd;

            ImagePartType ipt = ImagePartType.Jpeg;

            if (wsp.DrawingsPart == null)
            {
                //----- no drawing part exists, add a new one

                dp = wsp.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();
                imgp = dp.AddImagePart(ipt, wsp.GetIdOfPart(dp));
                wsd = new WorksheetDrawing();
            }
            else
            {
                //----- use existing drawing part

                dp = wsp.DrawingsPart;
                imgp = dp.AddImagePart(ipt);
                dp.CreateRelationshipToPart(imgp);
                wsd = dp.WorksheetDrawing;
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);
            imgp.FeedData(ms);

            int imageNumber = dp.ImageParts.Count<ImagePart>();
            if (imageNumber == 1)
            {
                Drawing drawing = new Drawing();
                drawing.Id = dp.GetIdOfPart(imgp);
                wsp.Worksheet.Append(drawing);
            }

            NonVisualDrawingProperties nvdp = new NonVisualDrawingProperties();
            nvdp.Id = new UInt32Value((uint)(1024 + imageNumber));
            nvdp.Name = "Picture " + imageNumber.ToString();
            nvdp.Description = "";
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PictureLocks picLocks = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PictureLocks();
            picLocks.NoChangeAspect = true;
            picLocks.NoChangeArrowheads = true;
            NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties nvpdp = new NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties();
            nvpdp.PictureLocks = picLocks;
            NonVisualPictureProperties nvpp = new NonVisualPictureProperties();
            nvpp.NonVisualDrawingProperties = nvdp;
            nvpp.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties = nvpdp;

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Stretch stretch = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Stretch();
            stretch.FillRectangle = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.FillRectangle();

            BlipFill blipFill = new BlipFill();
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip blip = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip();
            blip.Embed = dp.GetIdOfPart(imgp);
            blip.CompressionState = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.BlipCompressionValues.Print;
            blipFill.Blip = blip;
            blipFill.SourceRectangle = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.SourceRectangle();
            blipFill.Append(stretch);

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Transform2D t2d = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Transform2D();
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Offset offset = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Offset();
            offset.X = 0;
            offset.Y = 0;
            t2d.Offset = offset;


            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Extents extents = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Extents();
            //Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);
            if (width == null)
                extents.Cx = (long)bitmap.Width * (long)((float)914400 / bitmap.HorizontalResolution);
            else
                extents.Cx = width * (long)((float)914400 / bitmap.HorizontalResolution);

            if (height == null)
                extents.Cy = (long)bitmap.Height * (long)((float)914400 / bitmap.VerticalResolution);
            else
                extents.Cy = height * (long)((float)914400 / bitmap.VerticalResolution);

            bitmap.Dispose();

            t2d.Extents = extents;
            ShapeProperties sp = new ShapeProperties();
            sp.BlackWhiteMode = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.BlackWhiteModeValues.Auto;
            sp.Transform2D = t2d;
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PresetGeometry prstGeom = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PresetGeometry();
            prstGeom.Preset = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle;
            prstGeom.AdjustValueList = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.AdjustValueList();
            sp.Append(prstGeom);
            sp.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.NoFill());

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.Picture picture = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.Picture();
            picture.NonVisualPictureProperties = nvpp;
            picture.BlipFill = blipFill;
            picture.ShapeProperties = sp;

            Position pos = new Position();
            pos.X = x * 914400 / 72;
            pos.Y = y * 914400 / 72;
            Extent ext = new Extent();
            ext.Cx = extents.Cx;
            ext.Cy = extents.Cy;
            AbsoluteAnchor anchor = new AbsoluteAnchor();
            anchor.Position = pos;
            anchor.Extent = ext;
            anchor.Append(picture);
            anchor.Append(new ClientData());
            wsd.Append(anchor);
            wsd.Save(dp);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex; // or do something more interesting if you want
        }
    }
```

If I invoke the first method(use real file on the disk), it's ok, I can insert my picture into excel file. But if I read the file into memorystream and invoke method2, I can see the picture rectangle with error message.

So my question is how can I insert picture into excel via memorystream? Because I won't create too many files on disk.

Comment: Use a library like EPPplus to simplify this. [Check this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588704/adding-images-into-excel-using-epplus). The code required is 2 lines: `var picture = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(index.ToString(), logo);
    picture.SetPosition(index * 5, 0, 2, 0);`

Comment: I'm sorry I think I can't use EPPlus, because I create my excel file by openxml in memory, if I use EPPlus, I should modify too many codes

Comment: The Bitmap(ms) constructor call reads data from the stream.  So the Stream.Position is no longer at the position 0.  Inevitably the FeedData(ms) call is doomed to read garbage.  Adding `ms.Position = 0;` is a workaround but that can in turn make the bitmap misbehave, the codec used by the Bitmap class sometimes reads the pixel data lazily.  Consider not creating the bitmap object.

Comment: @user2155362 which is exactly what EPPlus does, only better. You won't have to modify anything, just delete what is already built-in - almost everything. For example, you can fill a sheet from a collection with a single `sheet.LoadFromCollection(myCollection)`. Same with `LoadFromDataTable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I have found solution.

I change memorystream parameter to string, and convert it to memorystream like below:

```
MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(str))
```

Now, it works.

I learn it from open xml sdk 2.5 productivity tool.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create bitmap image data from stream first

There's a solution already for that here on Stack Overflow: Byte Array to Bitmap Image 
I copy-paste the code from the solution:

```
int w= 100;
int h = 200;
int ch = 3; //number of channels (ie. assuming 24 bit RGB in this case)

byte[] imageData    = new byte[w*h*ch]; //you image data here
Bitmap bitmap       = new Bitmap(w,h,PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
BitmapData bmData   = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
IntPtr pNative      = bmData.Scan0;
Marshal.Copy(imageData,0,pNative,w*h*ch);
bitmap.UnlockBits(bmData);
```

Comment: You may want to add a link to the SO answer this came from