# cannot display multiple image in one columns when export to excel from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, excel

I cannot display multiple imagea in one column when export to excel from asp.net.
if IsDownload then

```
Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" & StrEncode(FormName,"FILE") & ".xls"
Response.Flush
```

end if

Comment: I bet you aren't exporting to Excel. You are sending an HTML or CSV file with a fake extension and deprecated content type. `xls` files are obsolete for over 10 years. Use a libary like EPPlus to create *real* xlsx files

Comment: In any case, you haven't posted any Excel-releated code, so it's impossible to understand what you even mean by `multiple image`. You can't build an `xls` file without Excel itself. The format wasn't documented, unlike `xlsx` which replaced it 10 years ago. If you use a CSV or HTML with an `xls` extension, there's no reason why even a *single* image should appear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding images into Excel using EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588704/adding-images-into-excel-using-epplus)

Comment: <td height="85" width="200">  in code, but when export to excel, height works, but width does not work.

Comment: That's HTML, not Excel. You are creating an HTML file that just happens to have a table, and send it with a fake extension and content type. Excel will *detect this* and *try to import it as HTML* using default settings. Build a *real* Excel file instead