# EPPlus insert image as Link to File in Excel document

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

In a Excel document, there is an option in the insert image dialog box, to insert a "Link to File", where Excel will display the image in the sheet without embedding it.

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlGbW.png

How do I translate that functionality with EpPlus?

Note: This is not the same as using the "ws.Drawings.AddPicture()" method as shown below, as the "AddPicture()" method embeds the image, which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

```
Image logo = Image.FromFile(path);
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(info);
var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test Page");
for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
{
    ws.Row(a*5).Height = 39.00D;
    var picture = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(a.ToString(), logo);
    picture.SetPosition(a*5, 0, 2, 0);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding images into Excel using EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588704/adding-images-into-excel-using-epplus)

Comment: You can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11880491/5077196

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question @YahyaHussein, unfortunately it is not what I'm looking for. I have edited my question to clarify.