# 'The file is corrupt and cannot be opened' OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, console-application, openxml

I got that code from **OpenXML sdk** and instead of `SpreadsheetDocument.Create`, I used `SpreadsheetDocument.Open`

This code is working and add an image in `.xlsx`, after image added to the file. I open the file which shows ->

> The file is corrupt and cannot be opened

If you want more details Please! let me know.

Reference URL -> https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-insert-image-into-93964561

Thanks for the help!

```
    /// <summary>
    /// add sheet in xlsx then add image into it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sFile"></param>
    /// <param name="imageFileName"></param>
    public void InsertimginExcel(string sFile, string imageFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath. 
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.
                Open(sFile, true))
            {

                // Add a WorkbookPart to the document. 
                //WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
                //workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

                // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart. 
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

                // Add Sheets to the Workbook. 
                Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
                    AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

                // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook. 
                Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
                {
                    Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                    SheetId = 1,
                    Name = "mySheet"
                };
                sheets.Append(sheet);

                var drawingsPart = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();

                if (!worksheetPart.Worksheet.ChildElements.OfType<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Drawing>().Any())
                {
                    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Drawing { Id = worksheetPart.GetIdOfPart(drawingsPart) });
                }

                if (drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing == null)
                {
                    drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = new WorksheetDrawing();
                }

                var worksheetDrawing = drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing;

                var imagePart = drawingsPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(imageFileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    imagePart.FeedData(stream);
                }

                Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(imageFileName);
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Extents extents = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Extents();
                var extentsCx = (long)bm.Width * (long)((float)914400 / bm.HorizontalResolution);
                var extentsCy = (long)bm.Height * (long)((float)914400 / bm.VerticalResolution);
                bm.Dispose();

                var colOffset = 0;
                var rowOffset = 0;
                int colNumber = 5;
                int rowNumber = 10;

                var nvps = worksheetDrawing.Descendants<Xdr.NonVisualDrawingProperties>();
                var nvpId = nvps.Count() > 0 ?
                    (UInt32Value)worksheetDrawing.Descendants<Xdr.NonVisualDrawingProperties>().Max(p => p.Id.Value) + 1 :
                    1U;

                var oneCellAnchor = new Xdr.OneCellAnchor(
                    new Xdr.FromMarker
                    {
                        ColumnId = new Xdr.ColumnId((colNumber - 1).ToString()),
                        RowId = new Xdr.RowId((rowNumber - 1).ToString()),
                        ColumnOffset = new Xdr.ColumnOffset(colOffset.ToString()),
                        RowOffset = new Xdr.RowOffset(rowOffset.ToString())
                    },
                    new Xdr.Extent { Cx = extentsCx, Cy = extentsCy },
                    new Xdr.Picture(
                        new Xdr.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                            new Xdr.NonVisualDrawingProperties { Id = nvpId, Name = "Picture " + nvpId, Description = imageFileName },
                            new Xdr.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties(new A.PictureLocks { NoChangeAspect = true })
                        ),
                        new Xdr.BlipFill(
                            new A.Blip { Embed = drawingsPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), CompressionState = A.BlipCompressionValues.Print },
                            new A.Stretch(new A.FillRectangle())
                        ),
                        new Xdr.ShapeProperties(
                            new A.Transform2D(
                                new A.Offset { X = 0, Y = 0 },
                                new A.Extents { Cx = extentsCx, Cy = extentsCy }
                            ),
                            new A.PresetGeometry { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }
                        )
                    ),
                    new Xdr.ClientData()
                );

                worksheetDrawing.Append(oneCellAnchor);

                //workbookpart.Workbook.Save();

                // Close the document. 
                spreadsheetDocument.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            //log.Error("error occur while creating sheet and adding image --> " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this an error when opening with excel? If not, then why tag excel?

Comment: yes, this is error when I am trying to open excel file after making the changes in excel file using above mention code.

Comment: First thing I would check is whether the generated .xlsx is well formed and valid XML. https://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: Are you tied to OpenXML SDK or free to use other Frameworks/Wrapper, which might make it easier to create/insert an Image to a xlsx file. Examples would be EPPlus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588704/adding-images-into-excel-using-epplus#11880491 or ClosedXML  https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/How-can-I-insert-an-image ;These arose, because nobody whats to work with OpenXML SDK directly if not necessary

Comment: Not sure how many workbookparts and worksheetparts a xlsx file can handle and if the ```SheetId``` must be document unique for all Sheets. Try changing the Id to e.g. 5 if that does not help do not create a new workbookpart for the sheet, use existig one, if possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FrankM for your last comment it really help.

Comment: @FrankM, Please! put your comment in the answer so I can assign you a bounty.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey: Done; 
JohnDoe: I am happy, my hints could point you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how many workbookparts and worksheetparts a xlsx file can handle and if the `SheetId` must be document unique for all Sheets. Try changing the Id to e.g. 5 if that does not help: do not create a new workbookpart for the sheet, use existig one, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> The file is corrupt and cannot be opened

Uncheck all the options under Protected View and confirm by pressing OK.

Restart Excel and try to open the broken Excel documents.

[image]

Ref: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/the-file-is-corrupt-and-cannot-be-opened-error-on/93af59c1-946c-4f5f-83c1-bd6f58dbd94f

---

If that doesn't work, typically when you create XSLX files and there is an error, you see this:

[image]

Can you check your Temporary Internet Files for the log. The log file should have info on what is malformed. Please update your question with any additional info.

Comment: Could you please confirm you checked if the log files exist? Also, when you ask questions on [so]  include your research, what you've tried and the results. This helps people not suggest what you've already tried. Please update your question.