# How to find a picture in an Excel document

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I want my code to add a picture to an Excel spreadsheet using EPPlus.

I know how.

However, I'd like to test my code.

How do I find a picture in an Excel spreadsheet using EPPlus?

Comment: The same way? Check the contents of `Worksheet.Drawings`. How did you add the picture?

Comment: already exist the about .

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588704/adding-images-into-excel-using-epplus

Comment: How does it already exist?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks. If you promote your comment to an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.